# Email Verification python eror

Tags: python, email

## 4 validation errors for ConnectionConfig, who to fix this ?

i test smtp server and its working with ssl. when i comment this code app works good but with this it has this erros

```
ConnectionConfig
```

```
`MAIL_STARTTLS
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'MAIL_USERNAME': 'jajani...'USE_CREDENTIALS': True}, input_type=dict]
MAIL_SSL_TLS
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'MAIL_USERNAME': 'jajani...'USE_CREDENTIALS': True}, input_type=dict]
MAIL_TLS
  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value=True, input_type=bool]
MAIL_SSL
  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value=False, input_type=bool]`
```

[text](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
conf = ConnectionConfig(
    MAIL_USERNAME=config_credentials["EMAIL"],
    MAIL_PASSWORD=config_credentials["PASS"],
    MAIL_FROM=config_credentials["EMAIL"],
    MAIL_PORT=465,
    MAIL_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com",
    MAIL_TLS=True,
    MAIL_SSL=False,
    USE_CREDENTIALS=True
)
```